# how can I fix the number of digits after the decimal place in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-fractions

**For Example**
this is my list

```
li = [4.0, 5.15445454, 1.1]
```

and I want to this

```
newli = [4.00000, 5.15445, 1.10000]
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/455634/10099100) answer explain more.

```py
li = [4.0, 5.15445454, 1.1]
newli = ["%.5f" % a for a in li]
```